# Can extundelete bring back folders after you have 'emptied trash' on them?

Tags: delete, trash

I read a number of threads about undeleting.   The best tool seems to be extundelete.  I tried it and it says it finds no files that have been deleted.
I was wondering if that was because I put the folder in the trash and then 'emptied' the trash.  I saw that it had freed up way too much space and then I realized that I had deleted a large folder by accident.  When I finally figured out how to use extundelete, it said it found nothing to undelete.
So, the question is, can it undelete folders that have been 'trash emptied' or should I just give up on the folder?
Thanks

Comment: The key thing after deleting it to do absolutely nothing with that part of the disk.  Use another machine to create a live  TestDisk (that one is the best) and use a LIVE USB to boot it. Don't touch the system and have TD do a scan,

Comment: In fact, `extundelete` is intended to be used on unmounted partitions only.

Comment: As soon as I realized that folder was gone, I stopped work on that computer and made the boot disk on my other computer. There was very little done on that computer.  I did unmount that drive.  I tried it once or twice before I realized you had to unmount it, but extundelete just gave an error message until I unmounted it.  I was just wondering that if you had already 'emptied' the trash, would it work after that?  I was surprised that it found nothing.

Comment: As I understand it, `extundelete` is a tool that can collect orphaned blocks on disk and reassemble them to files and folders, much like TestDisk does. If it merely could restore files from the trash can in Gnome, we wouldn't need it, as you can do that easily from within Gnome.

Comment: Then I really don't understand why it didn't work for me.   I read all the great experiences others had.  I guess even just a very small amount of activity on that drive ruins it all.  Hey. but at least I learned another tool and also to double check what I'm deleting,